# Image not rendering on web browser

Tags: html, processing, render

I got a kaleidoscope code from  Gary George at openprocessing. I tried to modify it to meet my needs and export it to web. But I'm having trouble rendering the image on the browser. It runs well on the desktop but not on browser. I've been trying to fix the error but...no luck (yet, I hope).

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Kaleidoscope   by Gary George.
 * 
 *Load an image.
 *Move around the mouse to explore other parts of the image.
 *Press the up and down arrows to add slices.
 *Press s to save.
 *
 *I had wanted to do a Kaleidoscope and was inspired with the by Devon Eckstein's Hexagon Stitchery
 *and his use of Mask.  His sketch can be found at http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=1288

 */

PImage a;
int totalSlices=8;  // the number of slices the image will start with... should be divisable by 4
int previousMouseX, previousMouseY;  //store previous mouse coordinates

void setup() 
{
    size(500,500, JAVA2D);
    background(0,0,0); 
    smooth();  //helps with gaps inbetween slices
    fill(255);
    frameRate(30);
    a=loadImage("pattern.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  if(totalSlices==0){ 
    background(0,0,0);  
    image(a,0,0);
  }
  else{
   if(mouseButton == LEFT){
      background(0,0,0);  
      //the width and height parameters for the mask
      int w =int(width/3.2); 
      int h = int(height/3.2); 
        //create a mask of a slice of the original image.
      PGraphics selection_mask; 
      selection_mask = createGraphics(w, h, JAVA2D); 
      selection_mask.beginDraw(); 
      selection_mask.smooth();
      selection_mask.arc(0,0, 2*w, 2*h, 0, radians(360/totalSlices+.1));   //using 369 to reduce lines on arc edges
      selection_mask.endDraw(); 
      float wRatio = float(a.width-w)/float(width);
      float hRatio = float(a.height-h)/float(height);
      //println("ratio: "+hRatio+"x"+wRatio);
      PImage slice = createImage(w, h, RGB); 
      slice = a.get(int((mouseX)*wRatio), int((mouseY)*hRatio), w, h);  
      slice.mask(selection_mask); 
      translate(width/2,height/2); 
      float scaleAmt =1.5;
      scale(scaleAmt);
      for(int k = 0; k<=totalSlices ;k++){ 
        rotate(k*radians(360/(totalSlices/2))); 
        image(slice, 0, 0); 
        scale(-1.0, 1.0);
        image(slice,0,0);
      }
   }
   resetMatrix();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does that mean "trouble rendering the image"... Is it displayed somehow wrong? Is it not displayed at all? Is there an error message?_Tell us!_

Comment: Sorry. There is no error message and the background is always black.

Comment: Runs well on the desktop but not the browser? What exactly does that mean?...

Comment: Sorry, the code certainly is _not_ html as the tags suggest. What _is_ it? How do you run it on the desktop? How inside the browser?

Comment: It means that it shows the image on the desktop version and when I export it to the web version it just won't render the image.

Comment: I'm using Processing: https://processing.org/

Comment: Can you provide a link to your image? What happens if you take the JAVA2D part out of your call to `size()`? Does *anything* show up? (try making a call to `text()` to draw a String in the upper-left corner)

Comment: @arkascha This is Processing, which can be deployed to the desktop or as JavaScript. The tags explain that.

Comment: @KevinWorkman if I change the `size()` it won't work either. If I put a `console.log("something")` however it prints the message on the console output stream :o

Comment: @nobitta But what if you try drawing text **to the screen** using the `text()` method?

Comment: @KevinWorkman the `text()` works well :o

Comment: So are you trying to put this as a java applet into your browser? Or are you trying to run it via processing.js?

Comment: @nobitta You'll have better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)- can you create a small example program that simply shows an image? Does that exhibit your problem? If not, narrow it down to the smallest program that *does* exhibit your problem.

Comment: @nils Run it via processing.js I guess. I'm using the Export for Web feature from Processing 2.2.1 IDE

Comment: Can you post the exported code as well?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I already tried it. If you change the `totalSlices ` to 0 it will show only the image without the computation concerning the kaleidoscope "things". If the `totalSlices` > 0 however it won't show nothing :\

Comment: @nils the exported code its exactly the same, I think the conversion is done on the fly through processing.js (I'm not an expert on this :o )

Comment: @nobitta You've got another JAVA2D in there. I'm not sure what Processing.js does with that.

Comment: Can you post a link to a live example? It is really hard to guess what goes wrong in the conversion otherwise...

Comment: @KevinWorkman well...me neither. But I tried with only one JAVA2D and also with P2D and it won't work anyway

Comment: @nils Sorry but I don't know any live coding plataform for Processing :\  . I just know that if you copy and paste the code to the IDE it works, you just have to add any image to the `data` folder (which is at the same level as the code) and name it `pattern.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things for loading a local image in JS mode:

1. Your images must be in a folder called `data` inside your sketch folder. You can just make the folder yourself and put the image in it. You still load the image as before, no need to specify the data folder.
2. In JS mode, you need to preload the image using this command: `/* @pjs preload="pattern.jpg"; */`

So your full image loading code would be:

```
/* @pjs preload="pattern.jpg"; */
a = loadImage("pattern.jpg");
```